# Click for Dropdown not working when generated in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that is populated from a database with a dropdown menu  that is populated along side the table which is generated from code in the php. Im tying to use javascript and css to make each drop down open on click but I cannot seem to get it to work. I've included the code below. I initilly had the script working but it only worked on the first instance of the dropdown. I reviewed a similar post to what Im looking to do but it was to no avail.

**CSS**

```
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.yardDropbtn i{
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.yardDropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yard-dropdown-content{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.yard-dropdown-content a{
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.yard-dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.yardDropBtnCt {
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  /*margin-left: 5px;*/
  border: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.yardDropBtnCt:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}
.trackBtn{
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.trackBtn:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/*.yard-dropdown-content:hover{
  background-color: #ddd;
}*/



.show_yard_Dropdown .yard-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.show_yard_Dropdown .yardDropbtn {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var dropDownDivY = document.querySelector(".yardDropdown");
/*dropDownButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  dropDownDivY.classList.toggle('show_yard_Dropdown');
});*/

dropDownButton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    dropDownDivY.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
   <td width='50px' class='yard8'>6400'</td>
   <td width='100px' class='yard8 track'>Receiving 1</td>
   <td width='150px' class='yard8'></td>
   <td width='150px' class='yard8'>
   <td width='250px' class='yard8 destination'></td>
   <td  width='100px'class='yard8 length'>3455'</td>
   <td width='100px' class='yard8 weight'></td>
   <td width='150px' class='yard8 status'></td>
   <td class='yard8'>
      <div class='progressContainer'>
         <div class='progress' style='width:54%'>54%</div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class='yard8 remarks'></td>
   <td width='59px'>
      <div class="yardDropdown">
         <button class="yardDropbtn">Menu<i class="bx bx-menu"></i></button>
         <div class="yard-dropdown-content"><a href="editTrack.php?tid=13">Edit Track</a><a href="aeiPopulate.php?tid=13">AEI Populate</a></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<form action="" method="POST"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector(".yardDropdown");
```

The `querySelector` method only returns the first element matching the selector, so it can never work for more than the first row.

You need to use `querySelectorAll` instead and then loop over all the elements found:

```
let dropDowns = document.querySelectorAll(".yardDropdown");

for (let i = 0; i < dropDowns.length; i++) {
  let dropDown = dropDowns[i]
  dropDown.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // do something, you can use the `i` variable to know which row has been clicked if you need to   
  })
}
```

Comment: That still does not work, when I click on the menu button no dropdown appears